# How can I parse JsonObject shows in Android showing as a foders?

Tags: android, arrays, json

this is my json response 
`result: [ { folder1: [ { test1.1: [ { app1.1.1: [ ] }, { app1.1.2: [ ] } ] }, { test1.2: [ { app1.2.1: [ ] }, { app1.2.2: [ ] } ] } ] }, { folder2: [ { test2.1: [ { app2.1.1: [ ] }, { app2.1.2: [ ] } ] }, { test2.2: [ { app2.2.1: [ ] }, { app2.2.2: [ ] } ] } ] }, { folder3: [ { test3.1: [ { app3.1.1: [ ] }, { app3.1.2: [ ] } ] }, { test3.2: [ { app3.2.1: [ ] }, { app3.2.2: [ ] } ] } ] } ] }`

and this is my code

`class Getdata extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ExampleActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        if (pref.getString("instraw", null) != null) {
            Log.e("Enter  Not Null>>>", "Not Null");
            spString = pref.getString("instraw", null);
            jsonRes = spString;
            getServerData();
        } else {
            Log.e("Enter Null>>>", "Yes It's Null");
            ServiceHandler handler = new ServiceHandler();
            jsonRes = handler.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            editor.putString("instraw", jsonRes);
            editor.commit();
            getServerData();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(ExampleActivity.this,
                R.layout.schema_item, R.id.textView1, list1));

    }

}

private void getServerData() {

    Log.e("ENTER-getServerData>>>>", "0000000");

    if (jsonRes != null) {

        try {
            mainObj = new JSONObject(jsonRes);

            jsonArray = mainObj.getJSONArray("result");
            Log.i("MAIN_ARRAY>>>>", jsonArray + "");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject Obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("MAIN-OBJ>>>>", "" + Obj);
                getObjMeth(Obj);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    } else {

    }

}

private void getObjMeth(JSONObject obj) {

    Log.e("ENTER-getObjMeth>>>>", "1111-->getObjMeth");

    try {

        Iterator<String> i_keys = obj.keys();

        while (i_keys.hasNext()) {
            String strkey = i_keys.next();
            Log.e("getObjMeth-key>>>>", strkey);
            list1.add(strkey);
            Log.e("<<keys-list1>>", "" + list1);


                sub_sub_Obj = new JSONObject();
                sub_sub_Obj = obj;


            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(ExampleActivity.this,
                    R.layout.schema_item, R.id.textView1, list1));

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

private void methFirst1(String list3) {

    Log.e("ENTER-methFirst1>>>>", "2222---> " + list3);
    Log.e("SUB-ARRAY>>>>", "2222---> " + subArray);

    try {



        subArray = sub_sub_Obj.getJSONArray(list3);

        Log.e("size>>>>>>>>>>>", "" + subArray.length());

        for (int j = 0; j < subArray.length(); j++) {

            Log.i("Test----->>>>>>", "test--" + j);

            JSONObject Obj = subArray.getJSONObject(j);

            Log.e("SUB-OBJ>>>>>>>>>>>", "" + Obj);

            getObjMeth(Obj);

            // break;

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

` 
i want parse above response and showing as a folders like ( folder1 have foleder1.1 and test1.2 are there and in folder1.1 have app1.1.1 and app1.1.2 ) like this pls help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Json [Here](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/).

--> Your Json Formate is Wrong It Gives The Error Change your json Formate

Answer (score 0):

`{
    "result": [
        {
            "folder1": [
                {
                    "test1.1": [
                        {
                            "app1.1.1": []
                        },
                        {
                            "app1.1.2": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "test1.2": [
                        {
                            "app1.2.1": []
                        },
                        {
                            "app1.2.2": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "folder2": [
                {
                    "test2.1": [
                        {
                            "app2.1.1": []
                        },
                        {
                            "app2.1.2": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "test2.2": [
                        {
                            "app2.2.1": []
                        },
                        {
                            "app2.2.2": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "folder3": [
                {
                    "test3.1": [
                        {
                            "app3.1.1": []
                        },
                        {
                            "app3.1.2": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "test3.2": [
                        {
                            "app3.2.1": []
                        },
                        {
                            "app3.2.2": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Your json structure giving an error when i am validating herewww.jsonlint.com.

try with the given JSON structure.